# The best way to assign the height of an object to be the height of another object

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have three divs in a body (class="a"), | | |
and in those divs is another div in each (class="b"). |[]| |[]| |[]|

how would you bind the height of a to be the height of b + 5%?
html, css or javascript.

Comment: use css variables

Comment: The height of a == hight of b automatically, but I would suggest using `padding` for class a instead, as the height could go horrible if 5% applied. padding will give you a reasonable space between `a` and `b`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If heightA = heightB + 5% => heightA - 5% = heightB => heightA - ( 0.05 * heightA) = heightB => 0.95 * heightA = heightB.

thus after selecting divs A and B you can set the height of one base on the other but one of them should have a predefined height.

```js
// the outer divs
const divsA = document.querySelectorAll('.A'); 

// the inner divs
const divsB = document.querySelectorAll('.B');

divsA.forEach((div, i) => {
    divsB[i].style.height = div.style.height * 0.95;
    
    // if the above line dont work try the line bellow
    divsB[i].setAttribute('height', div.style.height * 0.95);  

})
```